# Unable to debug ASP.NET Applicatation using VS 2008 on IIS 7 running on Windows 7 x64

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, iis-7, windows-7

I've been trying to debug an existing asp.net web application that requires me to debug against an IIS website.

I've installed the app and can navigate to it on localhost.  However, when I start VS 2008 as an Administrator and try to debug it, I get a message "Unable to start debugging on the web server.  The IIS worker process for the launched URL is not currently running."

I've looked through some of the help file contents and can't seem to figure out what is going on.  Clearly, the IIS worker process IS running, since I can navigate to the site locally without VS open.

My boss has suggested that it might be because my OS is 64 bit.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You must start the IIS worker process for the application pool,

1. Place a test HTML page in the web application folder. Access to this HTML page to initiate a w3wp.exe process for this application pool.
2. Attach VS debugger to this process.
3. Start to access the ASPX pages and do debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you are using the x64 or x86 debugger respectively depending on how you compiled your app.